# How to use custom color for each textview in listview that extends SimpleAdapter in Android?

Tags: android

I have a listview with custom rows and that extends SimpleAdapter. 
Each row consist of two linear layouts : 1st having two textviews of which one is hidden in horizontal orientation, second having two textviews in horizontal orientation.
Now depending on the value in hidden textview , I want to setcolor for the remaining items for the row.
To put it as simple:
 each listview item has some custom colors the value of which comes from the hidden field.

I have done this by overriding getview() for the simpleadapter and returning view for each, but this makes list very slow to render (and that I think is obvious as so much of work for each view before showing it).

Can I do this in some more efficient way ? like making views and then add up to list instead of using xml layout maybe one solution OR any other ? Any help ? Thanks.

Comment: making views and adding up will not solve the problem as the list has a dynamic search box that filters the list as user types, so will result in even slower performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `convertView` in your adapter, I would not expect you to have any particular speed issues. Creating and garbage collecting rows is expensive -- setting some colors on a set of `TextViews` is not. So, make sure you are using the `convertView` parameter to recycle your rows.

[Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that covers row recycling.